# Copying just the data from one Database to another

Tags: sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I'm not sure if this is the site for this question or not [if so put in the comment or vote to move it]

How can I copy only the data from one database to another within the same server on SQL Server 2005?

The two databases have the same schema but not the same data. 
I'm trying to get the data from one database to another.

I am not able to restore from a snapshot [that screws over the security settings on the database]. I'm not able to use the import data wizard, because that is trying to copy over schema data as well.

Comment: as schema is same so copying schema data should not be a problem?

Comment: It tries to create the tables where they already exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[redgate SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) is one option.